# Install a WinUSB driver

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, driver, wdk, winusb

We have an application which uses an off-the-shelf Bluetooth USB dongle (CSR8510-A10).
Unfortunately, our app needs better control over the BLE hardware than Windows generic driver can provide. Our solution was to write our own BLE-HCI code, which works great, but requires the user manually replace the generic BLE driver with WinUSB (e.g. by using [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/)).

Our next step is to streamline the user experience to something like:
 1. install our application, which can run some WinUSB driver installer
 2. plug-in the dongle
 3. --> Windows 7/8/10 should recognize it and use the WinUSB driver supplied in step 1

The dongle comes pre-loaded with firmware, which I cannot modify. It is possible, however, to change many attributes, including VendorId, ProductId, WCID etc, which we have - the VID/PID are now our own.

Questions:
 - Is it possible to install a inf file, such that Windows ignores the WCID provided by the dongle's firmware?
 - If not, is there another way to achieve this functionality, without modifying the dongle's firmware?

Comment: If it's just for your computer, then [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) should do the trick. If you want to create a device that will use WinUSB on all computers, then the USB descriptor should contain a Microsoft WCID feature descriptor.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other solution. What's the goal anyway? What do you want your Bluetooth dongle to become eventually?

Comment: What is a "HCI dri"?

Comment: We wrote an BLE HCI controller, which works with the dongle, when we replace the default driver with WinUSB using Zadig. We are looking for a way to achieve this without the need for Zadig.

Comment: @Codo - do you know if it is possible (other than using Zadig), to make Windows ignore the WCID, and use my driver instead (we can create a cab/inf file with the appropriate VID/PID). Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible with .inf files. But it's not my turf. You have hardly provided any information about the product you're using, why you can change the product class but not make other changes. If you provided more information, other people might direct you to solutions you'd never have thought of.

Comment: @Codo - thanks for your help. The dongle is a CSR8510 A10 Bluetooth controller. I can only change some properties of its existing descriptors, using a utility program, but I do not have, (and AFAIK, cannot obtain), the source code.